# To light a cigarette

Tags: american-english, british-english, collocation

I've heard "to light a cigarette" being used a couple of times, but I am still in doubt about two things:

1. Is this common both in American English and British English?
2. Are there other ways to say it in American English?

Comment: I wonder what else can replace "light a cigarette". *To light a cigarette for someone* could simply mean *being polite*.

Comment: Oald,  light, verb,  answers your first question. You can switch from English to American English.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/light_3

Comment: There are slang terms for cigarettes in both dialects, but the verb to *light up* is the same in both AmEng and BrEng.

Comment: The formally intransitive multi-word verb 'light up' is very-informal-to-slang, certainly used in the UK, for 'light one's cigarette / cigar ...'. It is a disguised transitive usage, as opposed to 'light/lights/lit... up' in say 'the screen lit up'. The type of DO appearing here is seen in 'light a beacon / lamp ...', but is semantically subtly different from 'fire' in 'light a fire' (the 'fire' in its usual sense not being present _to_ light).

Comment: There is absolutely nothing odd or awkward about the expression "light a cigarette", so long as you are outside and away from the entrances.  Yes, there are maybe a dozen alternative phrases, but most require more comprehension of the idiom to use properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidence from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=light%20a%20cigarette%3Aeng_us_2012%2Clight%20a%20cigarette%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clight%20a%20cigarette%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20a%20cigarette%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) suggests that   ***light a cigarette*** is equally common in BrE and AmE.

- Have you got a light?

[Slang expressions](http://slang.uoregon.edu/pub_socialsearch.lasso?SocialGroupCode=efacca1a482e4bd70b1a27305a2cb4b3&Process=detailSG01) related to smoking:

***Spark:***

> - (noun, verb) Source: the word spark relates to fire and in this case is simply referring to the small fire produced by a lighter. Meaning: to light (a cigarette). Context: asking someone else to light a cigarette.

Comment: How would you use *spark* in a sentence? "Give us a spark"? "Would you *spark* this for me?" ??

Comment: @Mari-LouA Where I'm from, *to spark* does mean to ignite a smokable substance wrapped in paper, but the substance isn't tobacco.

Comment: @DanBron OK... pot, grass, weed, whatever, could you say how the verb is used in a sentence? "Spark me this joint?" "Does anyone have a spark for this doobie"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  More like "Hey dude, you wanna spark?" / "Yeah man, the boss has been riding my ass all day". The verb *to spark* already embeds the object to be sparked. To mention both in the same sentence would be taken as a bit of a naive pleonasm.

Comment: @DanBron - I agree with "spark" being used for non-tobacco cigarettes. In my neck of the woods it is commonly heard as *"spark-up"*. As in: "What a day - I need to *spark-up*, or, "Your eyes look like two cherries on whipped cream - were you outside *sparking-up*? (NY-US)

Comment: @Oldbag so the source cited by Josh *is* misleading, spark has nothing to do with smoking cigarettes?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It may or may not, but that sense enjoys no currency in my (and it seems, oldbags') experience.